# Unity - Scale object, but not the sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, scale

First of all, I've got a perfectly accurate picture description of this problem but stackoverflow just refuses to let me help this issue and says I need 10 rep to send links. So no pictures :c

I want to scale an object, but when I scale it, it scales the sprite too. I need to scale the object AND keep the size of the sprite, basically it cuts the sprite in half or whatever the scale change. It kinda hides the rest of the sprite.

Thanks for help!

How it looks:

[image]

How I want it to behave:

[image]

What it actually does:

[image]

Alright I also noticed that in Unity 5.5 beta and 5.3 beta, it works like this but this option is not present in stable Unity

[image]

Comment: Has attempting to scale this outside of Unity worked? Usually the reshaping of an sprite(image) should be done in another program like Blender.

Comment: I need to solve the scaling in-Unity, it is a flat 2D sprite that needs to stay as it is, and just get cut by my scaling.

Comment: there you go some rep, can you upload the pictures now?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it only once, you can:

1. create Empty GameObject (i would call it "View") inside your object
2. move your sprite component into that View
3. drag the View outside your object in hieararchy
4. scale object
5. return View inside your object

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me - I tried adding pictures into the main post now :)

Comment: Well, you just need to separate big sprite into smaller tiles, and combine these tiles in the way you need

Comment: Beta Unity 5.5 and even 5.3 beta can do it, I wonder if there's such thing in stable Unity, take a look at the main post now